# plus; no distortion in it / plus, with no distortion in it, plus; there's no distortion in it

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, reading

Which form of tis text is better?

"Why are you so busy with Torah? The Quran already gives you whatever is in the Torah, plus; no distortion in it, so read it instead!"

or

Why are you so busy with Torah? The Quran already gives you whatever is in the Torah, plus; there's no distortion in it, so read it instead!"

or

Why are you so busy with Torah? The Quran already gives you whatever is in the Torah, plus; with no distortion in it, so read it instead!"

or

Why are you so busy with Torah? The Quran already gives you whatever is in the Torah, also with no distortion in it, so read it instead!"

or

please offer any form that you think works better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

> Why are you so busy with Torah? The Quran already gives you whatever is in the Torah, plus; there's no distortion in it, so read it instead!"

is the best but could still use some improvement. The comma and semicolon usage is non-standard. But I would just split it into another sentence.

> Why are you so busy with Torah? The Quran already gives you whatever is in the Torah. Plus, there's no distortion in it, so read it instead!"